# Is it possible to make this custom configuration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

Here is my xml structure:

```
<reco>
    <styleSheets>
      <group>
        <asset source="~/Script/file1.css"/>
        <asset source="~/Script/file2.css"/>
        <asset source="~/Script/file3.css"/>
    </group>
  </styleSheets>
  <scripts>
    <group>
        <asset source="~/Content/file1.js"/>
        <asset source="~/Content/file1.js"/>
        <asset source="~/Content/file1.js"/>
    </group>
  </scripts>
```

Here is my code:

```
public class AssetConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the source.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The source.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("source", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
    public string Source
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["source"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["source"] = value;
        }
    }
}

public class GroupConfigurationElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public GroupConfigurationElementCollection()
    {
        AddElementName = "asset";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true, IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["name"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["name"] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="WebAssetGroupConfigurationElement"/> is enabled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if enabled; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("enabled", DefaultValue = true)]
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this["enabled"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["enabled"] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the version.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The version.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("version")]
    public string Version
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["version"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["version"] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="WebAssetGroupConfigurationElement"/> is compress.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if compress; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("compress", DefaultValue = true)]
    public bool Compress
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this["compress"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["compress"] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="WebAssetGroupConfigurationElement"/> is combined.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if combined; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("combined", DefaultValue = true)]
    public bool Combined
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this["combined"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["combined"] = value;
        }
    }


    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new AssetConfigurationElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((AssetConfigurationElement)element).Source;
    }

}

public class SharedGroupConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the style sheets.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The style sheets.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("styleSheets")]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(GroupConfigurationElementCollection), AddItemName = "group")]
    public GroupConfigurationElementCollection StyleSheets
    {
        get
        {
            return (GroupConfigurationElementCollection)base["styleSheets"] ?? new GroupConfigurationElementCollection();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the style sheets.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The style sheets.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("scripts")]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(GroupConfigurationElementCollection), AddItemName = "group")]
    public GroupConfigurationElementCollection Scripts
    {
        get
        {
            return (GroupConfigurationElementCollection)base["scripts"] ?? new GroupConfigurationElementCollection();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this configuration even possible? If so, what am i doing wrong?

I get this error message when i try to get the section with the configuration manager.

> Configuration Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized element 'asset'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 96:     
>   Line 97:       
>   Line 98:         
>   Line 99:         
>   Line 100:
>
> Source File: D:\ASP.NET Projects\Resource-Compiler\ResourceCompiler\Examples\web.config    Line: 98

Comment: you should see and use **[Cassete](http://getcassette.net/)** instead of doing something from scratch... plus, it does support much more. give that a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working. I had to add two new collections for the styleSheet node and the script node. Here is my complete code:

```
    public class SharedGroupConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the style sheets.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The style sheets.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("styleSheets", Options = ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsRequired)]        
    public StyleSheetConfigurationElementCollection StyleSheets
    {
        get
        {
            return (StyleSheetConfigurationElementCollection)base["styleSheets"] ?? new StyleSheetConfigurationElementCollection();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the style sheets.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The style sheets.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("scripts", Options = ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsRequired)]        
    public ScriptConfigurationElementCollection Scripts
    {
        get
        {
            return (ScriptConfigurationElementCollection)base["scripts"] ?? new ScriptConfigurationElementCollection();
        }
    }
}


[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(GroupConfigurationElementCollection), AddItemName = "group")]
public class ScriptConfigurationElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new GroupConfigurationElementCollection();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        return ((GroupConfigurationElementCollection)element).Name;
    }
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(GroupConfigurationElementCollection), AddItemName="group")]
public class StyleSheetConfigurationElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new GroupConfigurationElementCollection();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        return ((GroupConfigurationElementCollection)element).Name;
    }
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(AssetConfigurationElement), AddItemName = "asset", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap)]
public class GroupConfigurationElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public GroupConfigurationElementCollection()
    {
        AddElementName = "asset";
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new AssetConfigurationElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        return ((AssetConfigurationElement)element).Source;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name 
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["name"];
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="WebAssetGroupConfigurationElement"/> is enabled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if enabled; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("enabled", DefaultValue = true)]
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this["enabled"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["enabled"] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the version.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The version.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("version")]
    public string Version
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["version"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["version"] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="WebAssetGroupConfigurationElement"/> is compress.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if compress; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("compress", DefaultValue = true)]
    public bool Compress
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this["compress"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["compress"] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="WebAssetGroupConfigurationElement"/> is combined.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if combined; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("combined", DefaultValue = true)]
    public bool Combined
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this["combined"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["combined"] = value;
        }
    }
}

public class AssetConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the source.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The source.</value>
    [ConfigurationProperty("source", IsRequired = false, IsKey = false)]
    public string Source
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["source"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["source"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you're trying to insert the custom section to the "standard" web.config file.
In this case, you need to register your custom section in the

```
<configSections>
```

and add a corresponding section there. For example (this is some Quartz config in one of my projects):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>

        <sectionGroup name="common">
            <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
        </sectionGroup>
        ... other sections here...
    </configSections>
    ... other web.config stuff here
```

and then, somewhere below you need to add your own section like this:

```
<common>
    <logging>
        <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4net">
            <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
        </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
</common>
```

Here's an msdn article regarding this topic:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It should be but you need a name tag for every asset as it is a required attribute for each asset. If you do not need this then remove IsRequired = true and IsKey = true from it. [ConfigurationElementCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) does impose stringent requirements how your data is formated in the App.Config. The Sytem.Configuration system allows you to inherit values from parent app.config file. This does even work for object collections. To make it work the MS designer introduced special tags.

To remove all elements from a collection loaded from a parent app.config the `<clear/>`
tag was added.

To add an element you need the `<add/>` tag where the data is seralized into the properties. 
Your app.config should then look like

```
<add asset source="~/Script/file1.css"/>
```

To support configuration inheritance you pay the price of a quite locked in serializaton format you need to adhere to. You can extend the system of course and add your own configuration provider which does it differently but this is not an easy task. At least much more complex than to use a real serializer like XmlSerializer where you have the most freedom about your data format.

DataContractSerializer is also good but it does not allow you to control everything. XmlSerializer is still the fastest and most versatile serializer for xml files.